# RealityKit placing object without rotation

Tags: arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to place an object/anchor in scene but every time I do it has a rotation. I can not find where the rotation is set as printing our matrices gives me 0,0,0 on rotation so I'm a little lost :

```
        let point = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY);
        if let result = raycast(from: point, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first {
            mLastObject = name
            var transform = simd_float4x4()
            transform.columns.0.x = 1.0
            transform.columns.1.y = 1.0
            transform.columns.2.z = 1.0
            transform.columns.3 = result.worldTransform.columns.3
            let resultAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: transform) // world ping
            let shadow = AnchorEntity(plane: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment.horizontal) // shadow ping
            resultAnchor.addChild(shadow)
            scene.anchors.append(resultAnchor)
            print("result : \(resultAnchor.transform)")
            print("result2 : \(resultAnchor.orientation)")
            
            print("shadow : \(shadow.transform)")
            print("shadow2 : \(shadow.orientation)")
```

Any idea how to access that rotation/remove it so it is aligned to 3d world not ipad rotation?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which object is rotated wrong, shadow or resultAnchor?

When printing, print out `shadow.orientation(relativeTo: nil)` if that's the one rotated wrong, and you'll see the real world transform.
If you want to set it to be rotated by zero, then once it's anchored in the scene call something like this:

```swift
shadow.setOrientation(
  simd_quatf(angle: 0, axis: [0, 1, 0]),
  relativeTo: nil
)
```

Comment: Yes the shadow is the "broken" one, but this does not work. Printing its orientation gives me 0 rotation. setting orientation as you did above does not work either. Its as if its being changed after placement/function end :- ( I'm adding geometry object to shadow. If I add it to resultAnchor, it works 100%, but shadow anchor is broken. Maybe I need to add it as async function or something like that ? Or how can I entirely remove the shadow anchor and have a shadow plane in resultAnchor? I'm lost, I don't know how to make shadow plane manually, place it and the anchor thing seems to not work

Comment: Printing shadow orientations/rotations/transforms/etc/etc relative to nil/resultAnchor always return 0/empty data. As if it all was set to 0. Is this a bug then?